# Xamarin - Android daily Scheduled notification in background

Tags: android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am trying to load time list from JSON object and want to show schedule notification daily on particular time(that is mentioned in JSON object).

to enable this feature in my app, can any one guide me what and how to achieve it?

i have tried simple AlarmManager and Broadcast Receiver but that is not firing simple notification.

so my code is as below, can any one guide me on below code, appreciate your help.

below is the AlarmReceiver.cs class

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(NotificationActivity)));

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(context);
    stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(NotificationActivity)));
    stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0,PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

    Notification notification = builder.SetContentTitle("Demo App Notification")
            .SetContentText("New Notification From Demo App..")
            .SetTicker("New Message Alert!")
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent).Build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
    notificationManager.Notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

main activity

```
[Activity(Label = "AlarmService", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
        notificationIntent.AddCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

        PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.GetInstance(Locale.Default);
        cal.Add(CalendarField.Second, 1);
        alarmManager.SetExact(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, cal.TimeInMillis, broadcast);
    }
}
```

Notification Activity

```
namespace AlarmService
{
[Activity(Label = "NotificationActivity")]
public class NotificationActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.notification_activity);
        // Create your application here
    }
}
```

}

And menifest file modified in Xamarin

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    package="AlarmService.AlarmService" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

<application android:label="AlarmService"></application>
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="NOTIFICATION_SERVICE" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Comment: Did you ever fix this?